# How do I call a component after use setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning React Native and I have a problem with the search bar, here I put my code.

```
export default SearchBar = ({ setPokemonDetails, pokemonsList }) => {

    const handlePokemonSearch = (text) => {
        const filteredItems = pokemonsList.filter(item => {
            return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
        })
        setPokemonDetails(filteredItems)
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Search Pokemon"
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    handlePokemonSearch(text)
                }} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Here is The Home Component, where I call de SearchBar Component:ç

```
export default function Home() {

const { pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails, setIsLoading, isLoading, isError } = useFetchPokemons()

return (
    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
        <SearchBar setPokemonDetails={setPokemonDetails} pokemonsList={pokemonDetails} />
        <FlatList
            data={pokemonDetails}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Card pokemon={item} />}
        />
    </View>
);
```

}

This code works halfway because it filters really well while you are writting BUT, when you delete some letters, it does not filter again. For example:

I have an array with this pokemons:

- Charmander
- Charmeleon
- Charizard

If I write 'charm', the search bar finds correctly there are only 2 (Charmander and Charmeleon), BUT if delete the 'm' letter, it does not show the 3 pokemons again and keep showing Charmander and Charmeleon.

Does anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What does "borrow the 'm' letter" mean?

Comment: Technical note: you're not filtering in "React native". You're filtering an array in JavaScript. Also, it sounds like the problem isn't with your filtering at all, but with "when does my component rerender"? (which of course _is_ a React Native question)

Comment: The filter looks correct so it's got to be with some code you're not showing

Comment: Edited both things, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to be able to better diagnose the issue, we would need to look at how you are calling your `SearchBar` component on your main screen. Could it be that `setPokemonDetails` sets the state of `pokemonsList`, causing this issue? For example, you might not be using two separate state variables to store the PokemonList as well as PokemonDetails.

```
export default function MainScreen() {
  const [pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails] = useState([]);
  const [pokemonsList, setPokemonsList] = useState([
    { name: 'Charmander' },
    { name: 'Charmeleon' },
    { name: 'Charizard' },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <SearchBar setPokemonDetails={setPokemonDetails} pokemonsList={pokemonsList} />

      <FlatList
        data={pokemonDetails}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I would make use of console.log() within `handlePokemonSearch` and see how `pokemonsList` as well as the `filteredItems` vary with text input.

Hope this helps in any small way!

Comment: I added how I am calling this component, sorry.

Comment: As Daniel answered, the issue is that you are permanently filtering your list, by using setPokemonDetails(filteredItems). Instead, we should filter the list, and put it into a separate state variable for output, such that every time the filter is applied only on the original list of Pokemon.

Comment: Then, do I need to set the filtered list to another state?

Comment: Thanks a lot! With this comment I understood what was my problem and I can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

When you `setPokemonDetails(filteredItems)`, you are permanently trimming down the list that `<SearchBar />` receives in its `pokemonsList` prop.  You don't want to alter the list when you are searching items, you simply want a filtered view of it to be rendered.  So instead of setting the list itself, you need to track a new piece of state for the search text and set that instead.

As an example:

```
export default SearchBar = ({ setSearchText, pokemonsList }) => {
    const handlePokemonSearch = (text) => {
        setSearchText(filteredItems);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                placeholder="Search Pokemon"
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    handlePokemonSearch(text);
                }}
            />
        />
    );
};

export default PokemonsList = ({ initialPokemonsList }) => {
    // For explicitness, setPokemonDetails is defined but unused
    const [pokemonsList, setPokemonDetails] = useState([])
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

    const filteredItems = pokemonsList.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
    });

    return (
        <>
            <SearchBar setSearchText={setSearchText} />
            <PokemonsList pokemonsList={filteredItems} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comment, I have a question, the filteredItems variable on PokemonsList component, should be on SearchBar component?

Comment: Admittedly, it raises some questions about whether the SearchBar needs to exist at all.  It's really only presentational.  As such, it does not need the filtered items, it is only responsible for showing the Search Input and passing the result back to whatever component owns rendering the pokemon list

Comment: Sorry I just caught that I was passing the pokemonsList as a prop to <SearchBar /> but as noted, it is not necessary since the SearchBar is just handling the searchText state